# Rails 3 - Compare Dates Upon Record Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an invoice model with date_received, created_at and received_state.

Upon record creation, I want to compare date_received and created_at to update the received_state.  Specifically, if created_at is greater than 2 days past date_received, received_state should equal red.  So, something like this:

```
if created_at > date_received + 2 days
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, red)
else
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, green)
end
```

I know there are date-in-words helper methods, but not sure how to use them in this instance.  Thanks for any assistance.

UPDATE:  I have tried the following.  No error, but record is not updated with either condition:

```
if (:date_received - :created_at).to_i > 2
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, red)
else
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, green)
end
```

UPDATE 2:  I tried the following, and the record is updated with red, even if condition green is met:

```
if :date_received.to_i - :created_at.to_i > 2
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, red)
else
  @invoice.update_attribute(:received_state, green)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to update an object before its creation, you should use a [callback method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) (`before_create` if your case), where you can use `self.received_state = ...` instead of `update_attributes`

For the date comparison, I'm not sure, maybe something like that may work:

```
d = self.date_received.clone
d.advance({:days => 2})
if self.created_at > d
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I tried: `before_create do |invoice|
    d = date_received
    d.advance({:days => 2})
    if created_at > d
      invoice.received_state = red
 else
   invoice.received_state = green
 end 
  end `  but get an "undefined method '>' for nil

Comment: @KatieM In `before_create` method, all attributes should be accessed with `self`. I've updated my post.

Comment: Thanks again.  I changed everything to "self."  The record is not updating the received_state at all (null), and when I go to view it, it's saying undefined method for true: TrueClass.  `def received_state
    d = self.date_received
    d.advance({:days => 2})
    if self.created_at > d
      self.received_state == red
 else
   self.received_state == green
 end
  end`

Answer (score 0):

I would have written:

```
if Date.current - 2.days > date_received
  self.received_state = red
else
  self.received_state = green
end
```

on a before create hook.